# Multiple errors when trying to save to DB using mongoose and async

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

i am trying to save something to a database using mongoose. The thing is i need to make sure the save was completed before i move on in the program and close the connection. Knowing that save is async in mongoose i tried using this code:

```
saveFunction = function(song){
song.save(function(err, userObj){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error' + err);
    } else{
        console.log('saved successfully:', userObj);
    }

});
};

database.prototype.add= function(newSong){
mongoose.connect(url);

var song = new songModel({id : newSong.getId(),
    title : newSong.getTitle(),
    artist : newSong.getArtist,
    genre : newSong.getGenre(),
    rating : newSong.getRating(),
    link : newSong.getLink()});


console.log("before async");
async.parallel([function (callback){
    saveFunction(song);
    callback();
}],function(){
    mongoose.connection.close();
    console.log('closed connection');
});
console.log("after async");
nextFreeId++;
};
```

^songModel is defined globally.

I tried lots of different  methods and changed lots of thing but i always get and error of somekind. With this code i get a process.nexttick(function() throw err ) error. I just can't get it to work. Can someone tell me whats wrong or provide me with working code?

I think optimally the console should look like this:

```
before async
saved successfully
closed connection
after async
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Open to other alternatives to async aswell. I just want to get this code to work any way possible. I just need to save/find something/remove something and it needs to wait with the rest of the execution of the program until the save/find/removal is done. I'm getting pretty desperate, lost nearly a day on this problem alone on a tight shedule :(

Comment: what output are you getting right now?

Comment: You probably don't want to be opening and closing the Mongoose connection pool each time you call this function. Just connect during startup and leave it open.

Comment: @ayushgp i am getting before async then afer async then saved succefully then connection closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a callback from your save function.

```
saveFunction = function(song,callback){
    song.save(function(err, userObj){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error' + err);
            return callback(true,err)
        } else{
            console.log('saved successfully:', userObj);
            return callback(null);
        }
    });
};
```

**Edit**

From your comment, the behavior you are expecting will never occur. You are expecting

```
console.log("before async");

async.parallel -> do your bits 
console.log('closed connection');

console.log("after async");
```

However this will never happen because `async.parallel` is an **asynchronous** call, which means that the execution **does not wait** for it to finish before moving onto the next command. The behavior you are seeing is

```
console.log("before async");

async.parallel -> starts

console.log("after async");

async.parallel -> console.log('closed connection');
```

Node is doing the first log, starting the `async.parallel`, then console.logging "after async". Then when `async.parallel` gets to its callback function, it prints "closed connection", so it appears after "after async" because it was executed after.

Any logic you want to perform that relies on the result of `async.parallel` **must happen in the callback function**. Furthermore, `async.parallel` is used when you want to run 2 or more functions asynchronously, then execute a callback once they are all finished. Your solution does not require async.parallel. You can replace that with:

```
saveFunction(song,function(err){
    if(err){
        //failed to save song
    }
    mongoose.connection.close(); //you do not need to do this anyway
    console.log('closed connection');
    nextFreeId++;
    //anything else you need to do here
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, got it to work with your help. Much love EDIT: actually i thought it worked but i still get the save operation done after "ater async" ;s Any ideas?

Comment: @user3764582 move `console.log("after async")` and `nextFreeId++;` into the callback function. see edit.

Comment: That doesn't change anything i think. I still cannot know for sure the save is done  when i execute code after the parallel call. (And it's not i tested it) . I need to make sure the save is done for good and the connection closed before i go on with my program. Currently it doesn't do that :s Thanks btw!

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'll have to rethink my program structure in that case. Thanks for clearing everything up.